# Converting matrices into a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am extracting data from my program and there are three matrixs `f_range_m, f_vel_mps, s_angQ15`. As of now i am getting separate matrices. How to achieve a 3D matrix where all the matrixs are togeather.

```
    %%%% Initialization
 f_range_m = zeros(length(mexTrglst_all),mexTrglst_all(length(mexTrglst_all)).ul_numTrgs)./0;  %%%% Range                 %%% Initialization
        f_vel_mps = zeros(length(mexTrglst_all),mexTrglst_all(length(mexTrglst_all)).ul_numTrgs)./0;  %%%% Doppler
        s_angQ15 = zeros(length(mexTrglst_all),mexTrglst_all(length(mexTrglst_all)).ul_numTrgs)./0;   %%%% angle

        for iCycle = 1:length(mexTrglst_all)
           for iTrg = 1:mexTrglst_all(iCycle).ul_numTrgs;
               if (bitand(mexTrglst_all(iCycle).target(iTrg).us_bitfield,1) == 1), 
                  f_range_m(iCycle,iTrg) = [mexTrglst_all(iCycle).target(iTrg).f_rng_m];
                  f_vel_mps(iCycle,iTrg) = [mexTrglst_all(iCycle).target(iTrg).f_vel_mps];
                  s_angQ15(iCycle,iTrg) = [mexTrglst_all(iCycle).target(iTrg).s_angQ15];
               else
                  f_range_m(iCycle,iTrg) = NaN; 
                  f_vel_mps(iCycle,iTrg) = NaN; 
                  s_angQ15(iCycle,iTrg) = NaN; 
               end
               % f_range_m = [f_range_m mexTrglst_all(iCycle).target(iTrg).f_rng_m];
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly, you wish to take these individual matrices and stack them so that they're 3D.  Just use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) in the third dimension:

```
out = cat(3, f_range_m, f_vel_mps, s_angQ15);
```